# How to Call an event when a specific item on CheckBoxList is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I've got a CheckBoxList, which is populated via .DataSource, getting some items from the database. Each one if this items got it's ID according to the ID on its database record.

What I need is, when the user clicks item with ID 34, it shows him a panel/popup... 
I already have everything, the popup and all. Just don't know how to capture this last item cliked.

Comment: You want to do it on the client side or server side?

Comment: You may want to go back and accept some answers from your previous questions.  People are more likely to help you if you give them credit for their efforts.

Comment: Please check the codebehind in my answer. If you catch the SelectedIndexChanged event and determine what the currently selected index, value or item is, you should have the specific item that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

try the following (and adapt it to your situation):

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Your codebehind might look something like this:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBoxList cbl = sender as CheckBoxList;
    Response.Write(cbl.SelectedIndex);
    Response.Write(cbl.SelectedItem);
}
```

Check if SelectedItem, Value or Index has the value you're looking for and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void chkServicos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList cbl = sender as CheckBoxList;
        Response.Write("SelectedItem: " + cbl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
```

I did this and it won't work as the .SelectedItem only gives me the first item on the entire list that is selected.. i need to capture the one that i just clicked in..